# How can I find a good description of .htaccess RewriteRule's?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been messing with .htaccess for more than one year, and still have no idea how to create a rule myself, I always look here or Google, or ask here.

So this time I want a "teach me how to catch a fish" request. How can I actually learn how to write a simple `RewriteRule` ?

for example, changing the url `mysite.com/index.php?lang=en` to `mysite.com/en`

I tried reading [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), but frankly it does not give any idea to me.

Do you know a good site that explains such rules, especially for those which transform `$_GET` variables in to url folder paths ?

If there is not any, I could take my time and create one right here.

But first I have to learn :)

Thanks !

Comment: I think that documentation is all you'd ever need to be honest.

Comment: Documentation link that you pasted is great. Next thing is to enable [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), so you can see your errors. And last, you need to be familiar with regex expresions.

Comment: you linked a single directive which is good to read all the tech-specs about the directive (setting). the detailed documentation is here (and is has pictures): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Comment: If you all say that the docs help, than I should look into that:) I also found this page which helps: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex

Comment: the regular expressions are the same as in php the preg_* ones, same PCRE library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like **[the rewrite rule intro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html)**, it's pretty well made and have images to describe what happens with the rewrite which is pretty handy.

As hakre said on the comments, httpd aka apache uses PCRE which is pretty much what perl uses and php `preg_*`.

There are ways to archive what you want.

```
mysite.com/index.php?lang=en
```

To

```
mysite.com/en
```

The first one is by creating an internal redirect and changing your links to it, which is the most simple and common used method.

This method will allow you to access `mysite.com/en` while giving you the content of `mysite.com/index.php?lang=en` which is an internal redirect.

However it does not block you from accessing the old URL or redirect that.

Here is an example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

The other way would be to redirect the other URL along with internally rewriting it.

So if you access:

```
mysite.com/index.php?lang=en
```

It will take you to:

```
mysite.com/en
```

While giving you the content of `mysite.com/index.php?lang=en`.

Here is one example:

```
# External redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# Internal redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

To exclude existent files from those rules you can use these conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

The above 2 conditions tell it to only redirect if the file and folder does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Prix!

I used your first example, and it works, but there are other problems. For example My page loads the css file from mysite.com/css/styles.css, but with this rule, it also converts mysite.com/css to mysite.com/index.php?lang=css , so How can I constrain the lang variable to be 2 chars, or one of "en" or "tr" ? Where does the docs tell about this? 

Thanks !

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw see update, and check bottom of the answer to see what it does. As for how to make regex you can use this site as example: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 0):

You really need to work off a lot of examples to start. Once you feel like you have a similar example to what you want you can test your rules using this htaccess rule tester http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: That site is pretty buggy and I would hardly call it a good reference. While some really really basic stuff work there the best is try on a real server even if just a sub folder for tests.